# Computing convex hull of points using shapely

Tags: shapefile, shapely, fiona, convex-hull

I have a points shapefile and I want to compute the convex hull of the points using shapely, and output the result as a shapefile using Fiona.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

This is what I have tried:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
shape = fiona.open('.cache/town_points/ny_points.shp')
with fiona.open('.cache/mew.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', shape.schema.copy(), shape.crs) as output:
    for feat in shape:
        ch_area = MultiPoint(shape).convex_hull
        output.write(feat)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To transform the shapefile geometries to shapely geometries (you can't build a MultiPoligon with a single point as in your solution)

[image]

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
import fiona

for feat in fiona.open("mypoints.shp"):
    print(shape(feat['geometry']))

POINT (270855.306991149 4458932.596754404)
POINT (270764.3725329859 4458995.357990075)
POINT (270854.1957680934 4458994.84736782)
POINT (270866.2151319417 4458994.87391199)
POINT (270866.2151319417 4458994.87391199)
POINT (270870.1540668578 4458992.662788996)
POINT (270872.9667142337 4458963.298747919)
POINT (270794.8588358188 4458943.977238521)
POINT (270762.3619021429 4458965.487104538)
POINT (270764.3725329859 4458995.357990075)
```

To construct a shapely MultiPoint geometry with all the points of the shapefile

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
import fiona

mpt = MultiPoint([shape(point['geometry']) for point in fiona.open("mypoints.shp")])
mpt.convex_hull.wkt

'POLYGON ((270855.306991149 4458932.596754404, 270794.8588358188 4458943.977238521, 270762.3619021429 4458965.487104538, 270764.3725329859 4458995.357990075, 270866.2151319417 4458994.87391199, 270870.1540668578 4458992.662788996, 270872.9667142337 4458963.298747919, 270855.306991149 4458932.596754404))
```

[image]

#### NEW save the resulting shapefile

The resulting geometry is a Polygon therefore

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
geom = mpt.convex_hull # the shapely geometry
schema = { 'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': { 'name': 'str' } }
with fiona.open('mew.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
    output.write({'properties': {'name': '0'}, 'geometry': mapping(geom)})
```